# Moving storyboard elements that are off screen

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm converting an iPad app to Universal. I copied the contents of MainStoryboard_iPad into MainStoryboard_iPhone and now I'm adjusting everything to fit. I can't figure out how to move elements that are now off screen. The iPad element had a bunch of buttons and labels at the bottom and bottom right of the layout. They copied over to the iPhone layout, but I can't get a handle to drag them into place.

How can I move off screen elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select an element in document outline, open Size Inspector (Command+Option+5) and enter  coordinates manually.

Answer (score 2):

Expand "Document Outline" (the small rectangle in the bottom left), you can now double click to choose the controls and move them by using mouse or the direction buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. Select the view controller in Storyboard
2. Select the attributes tab
3. In "Simulated metrics" select "Freeform" and give large enough dimensions to see all your subviews

You can then move them around and revert the metrics when finished